# String to object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string in javascript that looks like that :

```
array(4) {
["took"]=>
int(3)
["timed_out"]=>
bool(false)
["_shards"]=>
array(4) {
["total"]=>
int(5)
["successful"]=>
int(5)
["skipped"]=>
int(0)
["failed"]=>
int(0)
}
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to convert it as an object like :

```
{
'took':3,
'timed_out': false,
'_shards':4,
'total': 5,
'skipped': 0,
'failed' : 0
}
```

The received string comes from an ajax request where the response is a php Array

Comment: Your first thing doesn't look like a Javascript array to me.  A JS array would just be `['took','timed_out', '_shards', 'total', 'skipped', 'failed']`.  A JS object would be more useful given your data, `{ took: 3, timed_out: false, _shards: 4}` etc.

Comment: And neither does the second?

Comment: These are not valid `array`s !!!

Comment: 'took'=>3,'timed_out'=>false ... these are syntaxt errors

Comment: Braces `{}` are for declaring objects, Brackets `[]` are for Arrays.

Comment: Ok I made some mistakes. First it was object and not array. My bad. And it was from string to object

Comment: Do you have control over the array that you're receiving? If at all possible the formatting should be done on the PHP side.

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert the php output to json and do the miracles on the json records